# Can we use ip address as a url in selenium webdriver in c# to navigate?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have used the following code and it worked I can successfully navigate to desired page but I am unable to access any element available on the page like login button, user input fields or anything else. I also tried various methods to access those elements but failed every-time. I search a lot for this IP address thing but nowhere it was mentioned that we can use IP address to navigate so I think my issue is because of the IP address. Just clarify my doubt and give solution is possible. I am using selenium web driver in c# for chrome browser.

```
StringBuilder urlBuild = new StringBuilder("https://");
urlBuild.Append(ipAddress);
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(urlBuild.ToString());
```

Comment: Have you tried `driver.Url = urlBuild.ToString()`? As far as I know, the two should be equivalent but I use the above instead. Add a print statement before the navigation and make sure your URL is correct. If both of those work, it's likely there's something with the page... you are using incorrect locators, the content you are trying to access is in an IFRAME, etc. It's hard to tell without access to the URL or at least the relevant HTML.

Comment: Thanks, but the locators are all correct I can navigate to that url successfully its login page .

Answer (score 0):

You are using Navigate function, Navigate function does not wait for page to fully load so you have to add wait before performing operations Best way is to use:

```
driver.get(URL)
```

get function wait till the page gets fully load.

Comment: Thanks, But I tried wait also but still no improvement.

Comment: openqa.selenium.nosuchelementexception unable to find element with css selector.


For the above issue I tried all selectors, also tried wait logic and also used xpath but no. +ve response

Comment: did you try driver.get()?

Comment: i am not getting any reference to that method. I am just getting - 
driver.GetType() and driver.GetHashCode() but not driver.get(). 
I am using chromedriver.


Am I missing any reference or namesapce?

Comment: I am from java background i thought driver.get is also in C# . so after navigating please wait until element found eg:
 wait.Until(driver => 
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath")));